# Converting SQL int to C# string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I've been trying to load an INT from my SQL-Server DB into my C# application and convert it into string.

Basically, it's the ID/Primary key of the DB Table that I want to use as string.
This is what I do :

```
string Variable_ID;
Variable_ID = HandleDBNull(reader, "ID");
```

and I get a IndexOutOfRange exception.

Here is the HandleDBNullfunction :

```
    private string HandleDBNull(SqlDataReader r, string columnName)
    {
        if (!r.IsDBNull(r.GetOrdinal(columnName)))
            return r[columnName].ToString();
        else 
            return String.Empty;
    }
```

It works for the string columns so there seems to be something wrong with the conversion. I've already tried Convert.ToString and got the same error.

Any ideas?

Comment: `isDBNull` is a bad method-name. It suggests that it returns a `bool`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would guess that your `columnName` and `columnOrder` are out of step with each-other. One is wrong. Since they express the same information, one is redundant. I would use instead:

```
// probably should be renamed, btw
private string isDBNull(SqlDataReader r, int columnOrder)
{
    if (!r.IsDBNull(columnOrder))
    {
        return r[columnOrder].ToString();
    }
    else return "";
}
```

obviously with:

```
Variable_ID = isDBNull(reader, 0);
```

although I'm not *quite* sure I'd want everything as strings.

Comment: Please check my edited code. I do not understand why your example works but what I'm trying to do doesn't.

Comment: @hermann sounds to me like the column name is not what you think it is. Look at `r.GetName(0)`

Answer (score 2):

You can try with - Because your condition is based on columnOrder

```
 ... 
 return r[columnOrder].ToString();
```

Suggestion

```
private bool isDBNull(SqlDataReader r, string columnName, int columnOrder)
    {
        if (!r.IsDBNull(columnOrder))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplify the code:

```
string Variable_ID;
Variable_ID = isDBNull(reader, "ID");

private string isDBNull(SqlDataReader r, string columnName)
{
    if (!r.IsDBNull(r.GetOrdinal(columnName)))
        return r[columnName].ToString();
    else 
        return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, one less parameter now. Original problem persists though.

Comment: Same content replaced in question but no UpVote :(

Comment: On which line or function are you getting the exception exactly.